# deriving version numbers from a git repository

Tags: git, continuous-integration

we have a build system that uses the svn ID as an imput to a VM builder appliance that required a five digit number. When I build from git I have been faking this by counting the number of commits in the git repo. This only sort-of-works :-/ I'm tyring to figure out:

- how can I get a unique 5 digit number from the git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [git describe](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html):

> The command finds the most recent tag
>   that is reachable from a commit. If
>   the tag points to the commit, then
>   only the tag is shown. Otherwise, it
>   suffixes the tag name with the number
>   of additional commits on top of the
>   tagged object and the abbreviated
>   object name of the most recent commit.

```
$ git describe master
v1.10-5-g4efc7e1
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use the `--tags` option, unless you're in the good habit of using only annotated tags.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use **git describe** as said earlier, here is my rake task that prints out incrementing [semver compliant version numbers](http://semver.org/) automatically:

```
task :version do
  git_describe = `git describe --dirty --tags --match 'v*'`

  version, since, sha, dirty = git_describe.strip.split("-")
  major, minor, patch = version.split(".")

  version = "#{major}.#{minor}.#{patch}"

  if sha
    patch = String(Integer(patch) + 1)
    version = "#{version}pre#{since}-#{sha[1..sha.length]}"
  end

  if [since, dirty].include?("dirty")
     version = "#{version}-dirty"
  end

  puts version

end
```

Used like this:

`$> rake version`

`v0.9.8pre32-fcb661d`

Answer (score 0):

In git, every commit generates a unique SHA1 hash id.  You can see the id for each commit when running `git log`.  If you want a 5 digit number for the most recent commit, you could do something like `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=5 -1`.  For one of my repos the output looks like this:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=5 -1    
3b405... fixed css for page title.
```

You can experiment with the other options to `git log` to customize the format if needed. Of course, if the repository has enough commits, there's always the possibility that 5 digits will not be enough to guarantee uniqueness, but for small enough projects it may do.